# Run a non promise function in the middle of promise then

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have three promise based function, but I need to run a non-promise function in the middle.
For example:

```
function getListItems(listTitle) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            deferred.resolve(items);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            deferred.reject(sender, args);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}

function prepareSchemaData(items) {
    //promise
}

function someNonPromiseFunc() {
    //returns some Object
}

function updateListItems(items) {
    //updates items using data from the object returned by someNonPromiseFunc
    //promise
}

getListItems('aList')
    .then(prepareSchemaData)
    .then(someNonPromiseFunc)
    .then(updateListItems);
```

Obviously, i can't call a non promise function like that, but I Need to make sure before `updateListItems` can run, the `someNonPromiseFunc` can build its object and return fully.

Comment: "*Obviously, i can't call a non promise function like that*" - what makes you think that?

Comment: You could also write `getListItems('aList').then(prepareSchemaData).then(data => updateListItems(someNonPromiseFunc(data)));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
getListItems('aList')
    .then(prepareSchemaData)
    .then(someNonPromiseFunc)       // synchronous functions are allowed here
    .then(updateListItems);
```

just how you have it.  Your synchronous, non-promise function will be passed the resolved value of the previous `.then()` handler as a single argument (which it can use or not).  And the next `.then()` handler will be passed the return result of this synchronous function.  This will work just fine.

A `.then()` handler can return a plain value or a promise that resolves to a value.  Either will work.

So, you can use synchronous code as a `.then()` handler just fine.  Since it's synchronous, the next `.then()` handler won't get called until this one returns.

For this circumstance, there is no need to wrap that synchronous function in a `Promise.resolve()` as some others have suggested.  That would just be unnecessary code.

Comment: Thank you, I clearly need to revisit jQuery Promise documentation to reeducate myself on this better!!!